# How to send HTTP requests without getting the status/source code - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, httprequest

I know when you want to send HTTP requests in Python 3 , you use the following code:

```
import requests
requests.get(url = "http://example.com")
```

and the program waits for the website to send back it's status / source code.
But I'm trying to write a program that sends HTTP requests but doesn't wait for the website to reply.How can I do that?

***EDIT***
I tried to use TCP and UDP but neither works since I get the status of the website after the packets are being sent.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests and https://github.com/requests/requests-threads

Comment: can you add the code what you have tried?

Comment: @nandal It's been added

Comment: @SvenFestersen I did have a look at them but they both wait for the response because they print the status of the website.I don't even want to see whether the website is down or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont care about the response at all, you can use multiprocessing pool for this.

```
import multiprocessing
import requests

p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 1)
p.apply_async(requests.get, ['https://google.com'])
```

I assume the only purpose you would want to do this is when you want to make asynchronous calls without wating for a call to finish to start another so you can increase the number of processes and call asynchronously in a for loop as:

```
import multiprocessing
import requests

p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 4)
for i in range(10):
    p.apply_async(requests.get, ['https://google.com'])
```

Just an example, number of processes and async call can vary based on your processor capability.

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot.But I'm trying to make something like a server (not exactly a server) and this code doesn't seem to work if a send requests more than 1000 times.Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: What exactly doesnt work when you send request more than 1000 times?

Comment: It gives the error:"Too many pages open"

Comment: If this error is given by your server while serving the request then this is not related to the question you asked. For the question you asked, this is the solution

Comment: Not by the server by the python program

Comment: That is unliekely. Can you post the entire stack trace?